# An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have started my google cloud setup today.
Tried to follow instructions in interactive tutorial.
Setting up my First App that uses Node.js worked fine. But deploying app to Compute Engine failed with following error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I have added my account as Admin to 3 Storage buckets I found with my account.

Answer (score 4):

Try by setting this configuration parameter first:

`gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True`

as proposed in [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69192294)

If that doesn't work, can you provide the link to the tutorial you followed, so that the error can be reproduced?

Usually, it's a matter of setting the right permissions (as you pointed out regarding your account), but when you deploy your app to a Compute Engine instance, that instance will have to communicate with the Cloud Storage Buckets. This means that the [Compute Engine Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account) needs to have the proper IAM permissions to access the Cloud Storage.

You can also create a [new service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#newserviceaccounts) that your app can use to access specific resources in your Google Cloud Project.

Check your [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project) and/or [service accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project) to see the available accounts, roles and permissions.

Comment: Which roles and permissions are you talking about can you please tell ??

Comment: For example, `roles/storage.admin` to have full privileges over the whole storage...

Roles specify a bundle of permissions given to a specific account. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#gcs_name_short_roles) are the Cloud Storage roles described. 
You can either add roles at a bucket level or at a more general project level, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#using_iam_with_buckets).

Comment: It depends on what you want to permit to another user (through their account), or to a machine/product/application (through their service account). You can permit read, write, delete, full admin access, etc. Either per bucket or per the whole storage... More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Comment: Can you please have a look at my POST it would be really helpful for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430402/error-response-13-an-internal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-google-cloud-st

Comment: Also i am the only owner here there are no other users so I think I will be having all permissions for my app engine. Don't you think it is not related to Permissions ??

Comment: are you there ??

Comment: This issue is currently being investigated: [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69192294) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69623842)